# Survey with different response formats- how can this be validated

Tags: survey, psychometrics

I was wondering whether a survey that includes questions with different response formats (i.e. Likert-type questions, yes/no, open response, multiple choice) can be validated? I've been asked to assist with the validation of a survey, and I just wanted to check whether the different response formats would be an issue when validating the survey. In the past, I've only worked with surveys where response formats were consistent throughout the measure. I am interested in assessing the factor structure of the scale, and then confirming the factor structure.

Would it be a case of analysing the data item-by-item, type of item, or can all items be included? Many thanks!